# Lookup data in Excel matching multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns, vlookup, lookup

[image: http://imgur.com/BYejKRb]

As you can see in the picture above, I want to take Table 1 and, using formulas that can auto-populate, turn it into Table 2.

I tried using `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX`, but I'm not 100% sure on how to use the latter and the former allows you to only use one lookup value - I need it to be able to match up both the date and the product.

This needs to be formula-based because table 1 automatically updates based on a data feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will do it (*array formula* which has to be entered using **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**):

```
=INDEX($C$5:$C$9,MATCH(1,($B$5:$B$9=$E5)*($A$5:$A$9=F$4),0))
```

I assume that:

- your data of Table 1 is in A5:C10
- E5 has the value of "Widget"
- F4 has the date value

This array formula should be entered in F5.

Comment: Well that gave me something, but not exactly what I want... I think I am on the right track but I honestly don't know what's going on in this formula. Here is what I have [link](http://imgur.com/NOnBwxp)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I assume that if it needs to match another value (matching now: date, product. matching further: geo, date, product) then I can just add it using another asterisk in the MATCH part?

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is what your trying to do , then dont bother with the lookup in two columns,  just use a PIVOT TABLE and you will have the data in seconds  ,  you can refresh the pivot with one click or even automatically if you need it